# Можно ли писать на С++ со сборщиком мусора?

Tags: c++, сборщик-мусора

Пишу на С/С++, но вижу, что языки со сборкой мусора набирают популярность. Опять же надоело искать утечки памяти. В связи с этим вопрос:

1. Есть ли сейчас технологии, чтобы писать на С++, но пользоваться сборщиком мусора? Типа завел в программе объект - сборщик мусора и все операторы new перенаправляются на него, а он следит за освобождением памяти?

Comment: Вы думаете, в Java нет проблемы утечки памяти?...

Comment: @Harry Никогда не работал с Java. Если там есть утечки памяти, то это разрушит мой мир. Зачем же тогда Java, если там есть утечки памяти?

Comment: @pepsicoca1 на С++/cli можете попробовать со сборщиком. А в Java действительно память может течь. (циклические ссылки, статическая переменная, забыли занулить и.д.)

Comment: Ни один сборщик мусора не способен защитить от утечек памяти. Что бы сборщик отработал, он должен точно знать, что объект больше не нужен. А вы вполне можете сами забыть где то одну ссылку, которая не даст собрать за собой уйму объектов. Так что C++ хорош тем, то вы точно знаете, что ничего забывать нельзя. А сборщик даст вам расслабится, но что бы утечек не было вы должны будете еще знать кучу нюансов работы самого сборщика

Comment: C# пример как работает сборщик мусора без участия программиста :) а вообще если это gcc или clang можно посмотреть на `attribute clenup`

Comment: shared_ptr/unuque_ptr и мозг. А в java утечки ещё какие есть, просто их нельзя называть утечками - табу.

Comment: вспомнилось - когда то в java (jvm) сделали escape analisis (версия где то 1.6.45). После этого много кода чудесным образом ускорилась в десятки раз. А суть была в том, что нужно было отслеживать объекты, которые не покидают функцию и создавать их на стеке (или отдельном месте). А в с++ это было и есть много лет... Выводы делайте сами.

Comment: В книге Г. Шилдта "Искусство программирования на С++" описывается реализация простого сборщика мусора.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 Smart pointers

Comment: @KoVadim shared_ptr/unuque_ptr это конечно хорошо, но в сборщике мусора можно сделать такую полезную вещь как сжатие фрагментированной кучи. Даже и в реальном времени, если это дело выгрузить в фоновую низкоприоритетную задачу и сжимать не сразу все, а по частям.

Comment: только при наличии обычных указателей сжатие кучи сделать сложно. Но эту проблему частично решила 64 битная платформа

Comment: Кажется, вы не до конца понимаете, почему в C++ невозможная полноценная сборка мусора. Даже если вы заведете идеальный объект сборщика мусора и будете в него перенаправлять все что можно и что нельзя, проблема не решится. Например потому, что в проекте помимо вашего *супер-пупер умного* сборщика мусора будут еще какие-то модули, почти наверняка одна половина из них написана на C, а другая - подключается через всякие **dll** библиотеки и сторонние *полу-сервисы*. Таким образом, попытка ввести полноценный сборщик мусора в C++ аналогична попытке роскомнадзора заблокировать телеграмм. Невозможно.

Comment: Единственный выход - писать над C/C++ надстройку, которая будет являться новым языком. И использовать **только** эту новую сущность и ее *коробочные* возможности, полностью отгораживающие всю работу от C/C++. Как пример, даже если вы подключите в питоне или яве библиотеку C или C++, то в этот самый момент ваша программа становится неуправляемой в плане сборки мусора. И сборка мусора в этом случае вообще не имеет смысла, потому что подключенная библиотека может течь и портить память, никто ей этого не запретит с той стороны, с которой ее подключили.

Comment: В конце книги Джеффа Элджера "Библиотека программиста C++" рассматривается вопрос сборки мусора. Почитайте. :)

Comment: Если пишется под винду, и с виндовой кучей - у винды есть HeapWalk - функция позволяющая обойти кучу. Обход кучи и снятие статистики - иногда позволяет понять где утечка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть давняя древняя классика: http://www.hboehm.info/gc/

Дисклеймер: сам не пользовался ни разу.

Comment: Начал читать. Весьма интересно.

Comment: @avp список пользователей внушает)

Comment: Внушительная [презентация](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/04tutorial.pdf) с иллюстрацией принципов работы.

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, что-то его я не заметил. А вот [github issues](https://github.com/ivmai/bdwgc/issues) внушает сомнения в надежности реализации (а с другой стороны, жалоб на X-86 вроде не видно)

Comment: @avp http://www.hboehm.info/gc/#users

Comment: Похоже, что проект даже поддерживается. Последняя версия от 26 января 2018 года.

Comment: @bipll, солидный список