# Перевод из Java в с++

Tags: java, c++

Имеется такой класс:

```
public class Env
{
    private Hashtable table;
    protected Env prev;
    public Env(Env n)
    {
        table = new HashTable();
        prev = n;
    }
}
```

Вопрос в том, как передавать через конструктор объект этого же типа в с++?

Comment: Это копирование ?

Comment: Через ссылку. Просто добавить звёздочку.

Comment: @vegorov, это нужно для создания вложений, не копирование

Comment: я к тому что если написать `Env(const Env&)`, то это будет конструктор копирования. `Env e; Env e1 = Env(e)`, поэтому вариант с указателем (через звёздочку, как в ответе) пожалуй, единственный. Ну либо метод специальный добавить, типа `Env::createFrom(const Env&)` или `Env::createFrom(const Env*)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно понимать, что в с++ лучше использовать не обьекты напрямую а указатели либо ссылки. (объект - непрерывный участок в памяти, если в коде объект без указателя - он встраивается в scope-область видимости другого обьекта, для "самостоятельности" [т.е. что б не был встроен] нужно использовать указатель либо ссылку) Просто нужно добавить в местах обьявления обьектов - указатель(звёздочка). Кстати - `new` - возращает указатель. Для упрощения - в java тоже передаётся указатель, но синтаксиз упростили.

```
class Env
{
    private: Hashtable * table;
    protected: Env * prev;
    public: Env(Env * n)
    {
        table = new HashTable();
        prev = n;
    }
}
```

Запись `Hashtable table;` валидна, но обьект в таком случае будет создан и уничтожен неявно (new не требуется), и обьект имеет "стационарное место", т.е. его нельзя прямо так "копировать". В зависимости от конкретной ситуации так можно или нельзя делать (нужно понимать зона видимости и выход за неё, для table без new можно, для prev нельзя т.к. присвоение идет). Можно отдельно почитать про обьекты в с++. В большинстве случаев проще использовать `*` при передаче обьектов.

Я иногда путаю названия ссылка `&` и указатель `*`. Указатель может быть `null`. Тут речь идет об указателе, который ссылается на обьект. Вместо точки при указателе прийдётся писать `->` (например `table->toString()`). Работать с ссылочным типом или с обьектом без указателя в `с++` - несколько сложнее (зато там привычная точка).

UPD ещё немного. В с++ по умолчанию нету уборщика мусора в отличии от java - колличество new должно позже равнятся колличеству delete (что б небыло утечки памяти), но так же существует [уборщик](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/874159/%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%a1-%d1%81%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bc%d1%83%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0/874177) в виде отдельных библиотек.

Comment: что значит " что в с++ использует не обьекты напрямую а указатели"?

Comment: Пожалуй да. мы используем, а не с++ использует.

Comment: Тогда  Env  должен иметь еще и другой конструктор(конструктор по умолчанию), чтобы инициализировались указатели

Comment: Конструктор по-умолчанию... до определенного момента не нужен. (зависит от конкретики)

Comment: нет желания добавлять ответ, я просто хотел  чтобы все было правильно. Смотрите: если  конструктор только один,  т.е. мы пытаемся конструировать  обьект через указатель на обьект, который  имеет два сырых указателья, (не инициализированные). И на что будет указывать  prev после  prev = n; ?   Да, мы можем каким то образом сначала инициализировать  n->prev, но  всеравно нарушается инвариант обьекта

Comment: Автору вопроса нравится реализация с одим конструктором. Ведь  сделать `new Env(null);` никто не запрещает (как в ява так и в с++). Возможно это и нарушает какие-то принципы, но можно и так, и так как вы говорите.

Comment: @nick_n_a, как мне кажется, AR_Hovsepyan говорит о том, что надо бы переопределить конструктор по умолчанию. А то, если кто-то по ошибке напишет `Env obj();`, то получится совсем неправильно (бедолага голову может сломать от последующей диагностики компайлера)

Comment: @avp от чего там ломать голову? Компилятор просто скажет, что нужен аргумент. Конструктор по умолчанию не будет генериться, если уже добавлен пользовательский.

Answer (score 4):

При переводе кода с одного языка на другой возникает множество нюансов, особенно когда языки не имеют между собой какого-то родственного отношения.

В Java используются ссылочные типы данных, т.е. для записи вида `public Env(Env n)` фактически происходит передача ссылки (читай как адреса) объекта `n` в конструктор класса `Env`. Т.е. непосредственно до начала кода самого конструктора никакого копирования пользовательских данных ещё нет.

При этом стоит иметь в виду ещё такую особенность, что в Java используется сборщик мусора (Garbage Collector), и (по большей части) нет необходимости следить за временем жизни объектов, если ссылка на объект доступна, то и сам объект живой.

Суть вашего конструктора - формирование некоего линейного однонаправленного списка. Каждый новый объект `Env` создаёт таблицу и запоминает переданный аргумент, как некий предыдущий объект. Здесь стоит учесть тот вариант, что вызов `Env(null)` по сути начинает новый список, теряя все предыдущие объекты, если их не запомнить где-то дополнительно.

Учитывая необходимость передачи `null` в конструктор, подходящим вариантом использования в с++ будет указатель. Но так как в С++ нет сборщика мусора, а следить за валидностью объектов по сырым указателям не очень благодарная работа в современном мире, наиболее эквивалентным способом здесь будет использование умного указателя, т.е. обёртки вида `std::shared_ptr` (объект жив, пока доступен указатель и объект не копируется при копировании указателей, почти как в Java!) над вашим `Env`. А для `table` как приватного члена разумнее вовсе отказаться от указателя и хранить его по значению. Таким образом, результирующий код на C++, максимально близкий по поведению коду Java мне видится таким:

```
#include <memory>

class Hashtable { /* */ };

class Env
{
public:
    Env(std::shared_ptr<Env> n)
    {
        prev = n;
    }    
protected:
    std::shared_ptr<Env> prev;
private: 
    Hashtable table;    
};
```

Можно заметить, что в С++ отпала необходимость создавать явно объект `table`, т.к. он хранится в классе по значению, и в конструкторе `Env` создаётся конструктором по умолчанию (по сути то же, что в Java делается вызовом `new HashTable();`)